# Изменить цвет поточного эемента

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="game">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Есть вот такой HTML код
как при помощи JS без jQ
при нажатии на элемент списка изменить его цвет???

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
.element:active {
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: через JS надо

Comment: @hil400k 

    obj.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
    }, false );

Вам же нужно сначала получить список li элементов, вроде:

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#game li")

Потом разобрать его:

    for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        // добавить всем эвенты
    }

А можно поступить намного проще и сделать вот так:

    document.getElementById('game').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName == 'li') {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
        }
    }, false );

Answer (score 1):

js:

```
var div = document.getElementById('game');
var li = div.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function (el) {
        var currentLi = document.getElementsByClassName('current');
        if (currentLi[0]) {
            currentLi[0].className = '';
        }
        this.className = 'current';
    });
}
```

css:

```
.current {
    color: red;
}
```

[Рабочий пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLFmD/)

Comment: Тогда уж так, а то при 100 элементах чего-бы не загнулось http://jsfiddle.net/nLFmD/1/

Comment: @lampa, пожалуй, вы правы